# Need a regular expression to validate started double quote is ended or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Need a regular expression to validate a **double quote(")** is started and it must to be ended.
**Example** : **"This is valid"** but **"This is not valid**

Comment: Do you have to care about character escaping? E.g. is "Maybe valid\" a valid string?

Answer (score 1):

You could just count the numbers of quotes. If it's even it's OK

Comment: Yep, a regex is probably overkill for this. If you **have** to use a regex, try `^[^"]*("[^"]*")*[^"]*$`

Comment: @David: It’s rather `^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$`. Otherwise the quoted parts would be required to be immediately consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will work if no escaped doublequotes are allowed:

```
^"[^"]*"$
```

The `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the line anchors respectively.

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

Thus the pattern validates that the entire line starts and ends with double quotes, and in between there are absolutely no doublequotes (but it could be empty).

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

  - [Examples/Programming constructs/Strings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html) - Has patterns for various strings

Answer (score 0):

If count of unescaped `"` is even then the string is valid

Answer (score 0):

Even number of quotes (`"`) is valid.

For example in Python:

```
def isvalid(mystring):
    if mystring.count("\"")%2 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Unless this is an academic problem (or a constraint we aren't aware of) you don't really need to use a regular expression here.

Answer (score 0):

What language?
Wouldn't it be easyer to just take out the first and last character and check if it is the "-char?

Like this (in php):

```
$first = substr($string, 0, 1);
$last = substr($string, -1);
if ($first == """ && $last == """) {}
```

For RegEx it would be something like:

/^\"(*.)\"$/